# Chrome External Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to install my created chrome extension. If visit my website.

So for this purpose what should I do?

I have created my "manifest.json" and "javascript" files.

It work properly if uploaded manually (chorme://extension--->Load Unpacked.).

but I want to load it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't plan to share your extension and only use it for you, manually loading it is enough for the computer you use.

If you want it accross several computers either you load id manually on it each one, either you add your extension on the [chrome webstore](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish), and installing it from there will sync your extension accross browser and computer.

Comment: thank you for your attention. But when i am uploading  my folder on chrome webstore it giving me a error.

Comment: If you don't provide the error you have, I can't help you.

Comment: I have successfully uploaded my folder but it demand for $5.0 to publish completely. Is there any solution without money demand?

Comment: No, you have to pay. It's a one-time payment to avoid spam.

Comment: Ok , If i pay for this then after what should i do?

Comment: hello friends you there.

Comment: <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID"> . I paste a code that represent , we can associate my html page(my website in which user will hit) with my chrome extension that published in chrome web store. and  javascript function "chrome.webstore.install()" is it really make user to install my chrome extension in their computer?

Comment: @vickysharma Don't ask further questions in comments. This is not [how SO works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Post a new question if needed.